# R's browser() equivalent in Python

Tags: python, r, debugging, data-science

The title says it all.  When you are working `R` and using `RStudio`, its really easy and simple to debug something by dropping a `browser()` call anywhere in your code and seeing what goes wrong.  Is there a way to do that with Python? I'm slowly getting very sick of print statement debugging.

Comment: I guess you could use an IDE and set a breakpoint. Alternatively, `print(dir())` or `print(locals())`

Comment: I believe you are looking for the [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pdb.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for [ipdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb)

The basic usage is to set:

```
import ipdb
ipdb.set_trace()
```

in your code to explore; this will take you right to that part of code, so you can explore all the variables at that point.

For your specific use case: "Would it be a setting in my Console so that it Opens pdb right before something crashes" (a comment to another answer), you can use context manager: `launch_ipdb_on_exception`

For example:

```
from ipdb import launch_ipdb_on_exception

def silly():
    my_list = [1,2,3]
    for i in xrange(4):
        print my_list[i]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with launch_ipdb_on_exception():
        silly()
```

Will take you to `ipdb` session:

```
      5         for i in xrange(4):
----> 6             print my_list[i]
      7

ipdb> i
3
```

Answer (score 10):

you can use python's debugger

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

this will pause the script in debug mode

Example:

```
my_file=open('running_config','r')
word_count={}
special_character_count={}
import pdb
pdb.set_trace() <== The code will pause here
for config_lines in my_file.readlines():
    l=config_lines.strip()
    lines=l.upper()
```

Console:

```
> /home/samwilliams/workspace/parse_running_config/file_operations.py(6)<module>()
-> for config_lines in my_file.readlines():
(Pdb) print special_character_count
{}
(Pdb)
```

Comment: Would it be a setting in my Console so that it Opens pdb right before something crashes?

Comment: just write it on the script before where it crashes. it will pause in debug mode and you can just check the variables and see which variable is causing the issue.

Comment: @Adam, I believe you are looking for `launch_ipdb_on_exception`, see my updated answer.